# Need Help ... Grouping in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Please provide the code for Muenchian Grouping using XSLT1.0....

```
<list numOfItems="3">
<item>
<field dataType="double" name="DOWNPAYMENT">0</field>
</item>
<item>
<field dataType="double" name="DOWNPAYMENT">1</field>
</item>
<item>
<field dataType="double" name="DOWNPAYMENT">2</field>
</item>
</list>
<list numOfItems="3">
<item>
<field dataType="double" name="BALLOONPAYMENT">0</field>
</item>
<item>
<field dataType="double" name="BALLOONPAYMENT">1</field>
</item>
<item>
<field dataType="double" name="BALLOONPAYMENT">2</field>
</item>
</list>
```

Output should be...

```
<campaigns>
<downpayment>0</downpayment>
<Ballonpayment>0</Ballonpayment>
</campaigns>     
<campaigns>
<downpayment>1</downpayment>
<Ballonpayment>1</Ballonpayment>
</campaigns>     
<campaigns>
<downpayment>2</downpayment>
<Ballonpayment>2</Ballonpayment>
</campaigns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your key:

```
<xsl:key name="value" match="item/field" use="."/>
```

then process

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//list/item/field[generate-id() = generate-id(key('value', .)[1])]" mode="group"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/field" mode="group">
  <campaigns>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('value', .)"/>
  </campaigns>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/field[@name= 'BALLOONPAYMENT']">
  <Ballonpayment>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Ballonpayment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/field[@name= 'DOWNPAYMENT']">
  <downpayment>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </downpayment>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you're not too lazy, you would have seen that `<xsl:key name="value" match"item/field" use="."/>` is missing an `=` sign. Changing that to `<xsl:key name="value" match="item/field" use="."/>` should fix it.

Comment: @user3553819, I had a syntax error in the `xsl:key` definition that I have now corrected, thanks to Joel for pointing that out.